# I am unable to update a state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have state named responses which initially is an empty array. After I fetch some data from an API which is an array of object. I push each object of that array to a locally created array name `listMeals`. After pushing each object to the `listMeals`, I update the state named `Response` to the `listMeals` by calling `setResponse`.

```
import React , { useEffect,  useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const ste = {
  background:"pink",
  border:"2px solid purple",
  margin:"20px 0px",
  display:"flex",
  flexDirection:"Column",
  justifyContent:"center",
  alignItems:"center",}

function App() {

  const [responses, setResponse] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
      const fetchData =  async () =>{
        const  response = await fetch("APi");
        const responseData = await response.json();
        const listMeals =[]
        for (const key in responseData){
          listMeals.push({
            id:responseData[key].id,
            name:responseData[key].name,
            ingredients:responseData[key].ingredients
          })
        }
          setResponse(listMeals);
         
      }
      fetchData()},[]);

    const compare = useCallback(( a, b )  => {
      if ( a.name < b.name ){
        return -1;
      }
      if ( a.name > b.name ){
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    },[]);

    const sort = () => {
    setResponse(previousList => previousList.sort(compare);}
  
  return (
    <div className="App">

    <button onClick={sort}>Sort</button>

      {responses.map(each => {
        return <div style={ste} key={each.id}>
                  <h2>{each.name}</h2>
                  {each.ingredients.map(ingr =>
                  {return <ul key={Math.random()}>
                          <li>{ingr.name}</li>
                          <li>{ingr.quantity}</li>
                          <li>{ingr.quantity_type}</li>
                          </ul>} )}</div>
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Later on I want to sort the Array in descending order when I press the button named sort, for which I use sort() on the previous state but the state is not being updated. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array *in place* and returns the reference to the same array, now sorted.

This means you're not actually setting a new state, but instead are *mutating* state.  Which you shouldn't do for exactly this reason, the framework isn't aware of it and isn't expecting it.

Instead, spread the array contents into a *new* array, sort that, and set state to that new array.  For example:

```
const sort = () => {
  setResponse(previousList => [...previousList].sort(compare));
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Is there any specific reason for this? because I also tried creating a variable which did the sorting outside of the Sort function and the sort function was only changing the setResponse to that particular variable but it did not work. just wondering

Comment: @AbdulHaseebAhmadBashir: The reason is the difference between mutating state and replacing state.  If state is an object or array and you modify the existing instance but still use that same instance then React has no way to know it's been updated.  But if you replace that instance with a new instance (constructed from the same internal data) then React sees the new object reference and knows state has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

How said [David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75609385/21314808) you can spread, but it isn't main problem in your case

Try please close your setResponse function, because it isn't closed

```
const sort = () => {
    setResponse(previousList => previousList.sort(compare));
}
```

Special for you, with love <3